# Javascript object refers to a value in itself

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a state object for a form, each element of the object has its own validator, I need to check if the confirmationPassword is the same as the password, but I can't refer to the password value inside the object itself, how could I solve this?

```
const initalState = {
    code: { value: '', error: false, validator: value => value.length > 0 },
    email: { value: '', error: false, validator: validators.email },
    password: { value: '', error: false, validator: validators.password },
    confirmPassword: {
        value: '',
        error: false,
        validator: (password, confirmPassword) => password === confirmPassword,
    },
};
```

I'd like the code above to become something like

```
const initalState = {
    code: { value: '', error: false, validator: value => value.length > 0 },
    email: { value: '', error: false, validator: validators.email },
    password: { value: '', error: false, validator: validators.password },
    confirmPassword: {
        value: '',
        error: false,
        validator: value => value === this.password.value,
    },
};
```

As you can see validators for email and password are taken from another object.
In the `confirmPassword.validator` function I need to compare its value with the password one to check if they match.
When I call `confirmPassword.validator` the value that I pass is the `confirmPassword.value` itself, I'd just need to get `password.value` somehow

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the object and then add the rest of properties, that way you can reference it.

```js
const initalState = {};
Object.assign(initalState, {
    code: { value: '', error: false, validator: value => value.length > 0 },
    email: { value: '', error: false, validator: initalState.email },
    password: { value: '', error: false, validator: initalState.password },
    confirmPassword: {
        value: '',
        error: false,
        validator: value => value === this.password.value,
    },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I call `initialState.confirmPassword.validator('someValue')` it returns "Cannot read property 'password' of undefined"